# Spring Boot Defining A Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this funny error, I say it is funny because my project was working and it just crashed.

I believe I have implemented everything I was supposed to implement to achieve the multi data source.

Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'quoteController' defined in file [C:\Users\S4\Desktop\S4Projects\wirk-devserv-intranet\source\back-end\target\classes\com\api\controllers\QuoteController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'quoteServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\S4\Desktop\S4Projects\wirk-devserv-intranet\source\back-end\target\classes\com\api\services\implementation\QuoteServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.api.repository.customer.CustomerRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.api.services.implementation.QuoteServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.api.repository.customer.CustomerRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.api.repository.customer.CustomerRepository' in your configuration.

```
@Autowired
private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
@Autowired
private final QuoteRepository quoteRepository;


@Component
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, 
 Integer> {
 }
```

Config File

```
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackageClasses = {
   QuoteRepository.class, 
     CustomerConfig.class
},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "quoteEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "quoteTransactionManager")

public class QuoteConfig {

@Bean(name = "quoteEntityManager")
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean quoteEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("quoteDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages(Quote.class)
            .persistenceUnit("S4DevservIntranet")
            .build();
}

@Primary
@Bean("quoteDataSource")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource quoteDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Primary
@Bean("quoteTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager quoteTransactionManager(@Qualifier("quoteEntityManager") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean quoteEntityManager) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(quoteEntityManager.getObject()));
}
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here for anyone in the world to be able to help you. The error message already tells you everything: you have no bean of type CustomerRepository

Comment: Please look at the images attached. I have that bean. @Michael

Comment: Don't add code as image, put the code directly in the question (in the editor field you can add code tags to properly annotate it).

Comment: Also, two of your images are so blurry, that they are not readable, that's one of the reasons why you shouldn't add images of code.

Comment: Your `QuoteConfig` appears to be missing an `@Configuration` annotation. Please remove the `@Component` from your repository interface it isn't needed when using Spring Data.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry I mistakenly left that when I was copying the code, it is there. I added the component because I have been trying a lot of possible code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use @Component annotation since you use the spring-data JpaRepository interface. but if you wouldn't you have to use @Repository annotation.
2. In this part you add CustomerConfig class instead CustomerRepository in the list of JpaRepositories

```java
 @EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackageClasses = {
   QuoteRepository.class, 
     CustomerConfig.class
},
```

It must be:

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = {
       QuoteRepository.class, 
         CustomerRepository.class
    },
```

Comment: I first got this after implementing your solution.
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` 
I then added this suggested line to properties, the after adding it I am getting this error Error creating bean with name 'quoteController' defined, UnsatisfiedDependencyException.

Comment: You shouldn't use spring.main.allow-bean-definition, it is really bad practice. Instead, it is possible to configure bean name in Component, Bean  etc. annotation value in case you have beans with the same class name (that actually bad practice as well). If after applying this fix you have quoteController injection issue, it means that repository injection prettyMuch fixed., but you have one more injection issue.

Comment: That means you haven't bean of class QuoteController , or bean with name "quoteController", or it is not marked as Controller or RestController (in depends what you try to achive), or just your configuration not includes path to scan your bean, but if you use standard spring boot configuration it shouldn't be a problem. Anyway there no much details provided to say exactly.

Comment: The controller I am not using anywhere(not injected on injecting the services to the controller as the standard practice). And I am using Lombok to initialize the constructor.

Comment: `@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin({"http://localhost:4200"})
public class QuoteController {
    private final QuoteServiceImpl quoteService;`

Comment: This does not make sense to me, because this is the first thing I implemented and the project was running smoothly and now it crashes.

Comment: Looks Fine. Send please controller error full message and definition of QuoteService

Comment: `@AllArgsConstructor
@Transactional
@Slf4j
@Service
public class QuoteServiceImpl implements QuoteService {
    @Autowired
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final QuoteRepository quoteRepository;`

Answer (score -1):

Error Message tells it everything, seems you haven't created bean for CustomerRepository, so annotate the class with @Repository or @Component.

Comment: I did add those with no luck and did the add the entityscan and componentscan on the spring boot application but no luck.

Comment: And please look at the images attached.

Comment: Adding either of those to a Spring Data repository, besides hurting my eyes, doesn't add anything. Spring Data has other ways of detecting repositories. The `@Repository` is only useful when annotating classes with a dedicated implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum that's what I read/know as a beginner annotating the repository in Spring Date is unnecessary.